# Rounding of Decimal values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Is there any function in sql which rounds of the value to nearest whole number.

For example,

- If value is 12.56 then it should be 13.
- If value is 12.34 then it should be 12.

I tried with Ceiling and floor but it doesn't give me accurate result. Ceiling gives me both the value as 13 where as i need 13 and 12 depending on my value. 
Is there any function that i can use to get the desired result I want?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried... drumroll please... `ROUND()`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
I just used ROUND(value,0) which gave me desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about your decimal values being saved, like the people said ROUND() will work, just pass the second parameter as 0 to say that you don't care about the decimal places, Precision = 0 = NO Decimal, so for example:

```
DECLARE @floater FLOAT = 2.50

SELECT ROUND(@floater, 0)  --Returns 3

SET @floater = 2.10

SELECT ROUND(@floater, 0)  --Returns 2
```